# How to handle asynchronicity on Android Java?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, callback

I'm using OkHttp to send REST requests to the server, and the responses are returned asynchronously. Since Java is primarily a server-side language, the concept of handling asynchronous returns are vague to me.

For example, I want to send 3 requests A, B and C. After receiving all 3 returns of them, I'll perform an operation D on the mobile application.

I did it with callbacks like this:

```
do {
    run A asynchronously; A returns;
        -> run B asynchronously; B returns 
             -> run C asynchronously; C returns 
                 -> run D synchronously;
}
```

Visualization: It should be like this:

```
do {
    run A asynchronously;
    run B asynchronously;
    run C asynchronously;
}
await (A, B, C all returned) {
    run D synchronously;
}
```

How do I do it like the above await on Javascript?

Comment: different (additional) frameworks make this type of thing slightly more possible, i'm not sure if you can achieve this using just Okhttp, but with Rxjava you could zip these operations

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Retrofit`, which uses `OkHttp`
What about using coroutines? an approach like this?

```
GlobalScope.launch{
 responseA = async{ getAsynch1() }
 responseB = async{ getAsynch2() }
 responseC  = async{ getAsynch3() }
 handleResponseA(responseA.await())
 handleResponseB(responseB.await())
 handleResponseC(responseC.await())
}
```

reference: link https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067

Comment: doesn't help if OP is using java, which they said they are